# Special Characters break Generated URLs

Tags: php, .htaccess, friendly-url

I have an automated process which generates urls from the title of venue.

I then use the following line to within my .htaccess to get the url to redirect to the correct path

```
RewriteRule ^recipes/([\w-]+)/(\d+)$  ./recipes_news.php?i=$2 [L,QSA]
```

a typical URL looks like the link below

```
www.site.com/recipes/red-curry-chicken/123
```

Where the last part of the url is the id used to find the actual recipe information.

For some reason unknown to me, anytime a special character such as "ā" occurs, it breaks the url.

Is there something I am missing in the .htaccess code to capture special chacters?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your regex pattern to:

```
RewriteRule ^recipes/([^/]+)/(\d+)$  ./recipes_news.php?i=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I will test this today. Thanks for the contribution

Comment: does that mean the first section will capture any character format?

Comment: @JmsBnd Yes, anything exception for a `/`